# wordpress image src in automatically added another website path

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins, src

Image src tag in automatically added dummy site name and all attributes of image are dummy
`<img alt="my site" title="About 11" data-src="https://i0.wp.com/mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Award2014-scaled.jpg?fit=500%2C540&amp;ssl=1" class="swiper-slide-image lazyloaded" src="https://i0.wp.com/mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Award2014-scaled.jpg?fit=500%2C540&amp;ssl=1">`

Before "mysite.com" the "10.wp.com" is automatically added.
am not using any currepted or nulled plugins

Comment: Could you please clarify what your question is? It sounds like a statement now

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `WordPress.com`, this is very standard. If you're hosting your own install of `WordPress.org`, it's not, but I believe can be enabled through the JetPack plugin.

It's actually a built in part of WordPress.com's hosting. WordPress used to use Photon (now Site Accelerator) to host images and deliver them via CDN. You can read more about that here: https://jetpack.com/support/site-accelerator/